# Интеграция Facebook SDK в Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebooksdk, ads

Такой вопрос, клиент хочет, что в его `Android` приложение интегрировали `Facebook SDK`, что бы потом можно было рекламировать данное приложение в Facebook. Должен ли клиент создать свой личный `Facebook developer account`? Или я могу добавить его приложения через свой `Facebook developer account`? Если я добавлю эти приложения через свой аккаунт, сможет ли потом клиент проводить `Facebook ad campaigns`? Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение, клиент создает свой `Facebook developer account`, после чего в Ролях назначает человека, либо, как администратора, либо, как разработчика. После этого человек получает доступ к `Facebook developer account`.